# D3 Version 4: Axis without the whole D3.js

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg, reactjs

I'm new to d3 and I created some graphs with the whole d3.js and it works perfectly. But after building the whole JavaScript I saw that the final javascript file was too big for mobile.

After some research, I figured out that d3 provides some modules as standalone (p.e: d3-shape, d3-axis, d3-scale).

This fits perfectly for me, because I use React and like to use React as visualisation layer.

I just need a barChart with an x and y axis. The "react" bar charts I created with the help of d3-shape:

```
let max = Math.max.apply(Math, this.props.data.map(function(o){ return o.x; }))
    max = max + 5;

    let yScale = d3_scale.scaleLinear()
          .domain([0, max])
          .range([0, this.props.height]);

    let xScale = d3_scale.scaleLinear()
          .domain([0, this.props.data.length])
          .range([0, this.props.width]);

    let getColor = this.getColor.bind(this)

    let barWidth = this.getBarWidth()

    let bars = this.props.data.map(function(point, i) {
      console.log("point", point, point['x'])

      return (
        <Bar height={yScale(point['x'])} width={barWidth} offset={xScale(point['y'])} availableHeight={props.height} color={getColor(point.group)} key={i} />
      )
    });

    return (
      <g>{bars}</g>
    );
```

Bar.js

```
render() {
    return (
      <rect fill={this.props.color}
       width={this.props.width} height={this.props.height}
       x={this.props.offset} y={this.props.availableHeight - this.props.height} />
    )
  }
```

I googled for a solution, but every example use the d3.svg ... and this is currently the whole d3 package.

Does anybody of you are able to explain to me how I can add axis to this BarChart without loading the whole d3.js ?

Thanks
Marcel

**Update 29.06.2016:**

D3 releases the new version 4.0 and there are good examples now:

for this ticket: https://github.com/d3/d3-axis/blob/master/README.md this is helpfull

Comment: Did you tried to use `d3.min.js` ? It's only 140 KB

Comment: Yes i used this one. But with the current solution - d3-shape, d3-axis AND d3-scale its aprox 20 - 23 kb. This is a huge different. BTW: React is too much too, but i cannot change this :/

Comment: You are using `d3_scale`, a standalone module that does not require `d3`. What exactly is the problem here?

Comment: How can i add a Axis to my bar chart?

Comment: Without using the whole d3.js